# Getting intersection between existing layer and drawn shape

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

**EDIT** I now get the right layer from map, so the question now sums up to knowing if a layer A which contains curves, intersectects layer B which contains a surface which can be a circle or a polygon that was just drawn. I tried turf library's turf.intersect but I get "cyclic object reference" from that library.
And I am already looping through the curves seperaterly, to the question is now "Does a curve intersect with a shape.
Also tried: ol.extent.getIntersection(...) but it work only with extents wich are rectangle and therefore give very imprecise results.

I have a map and a layer that is built and added through

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector{(...)};
map.addLayer(layer);
```

And I add a layer through interaction, as shown in this example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/draw-features.html?q=draw
(We use the Circle selection.)

I would like to get he intersection between the lines in the fist layer and the shape (surface) drawn through interaction.

So far, I know that I can catch the event:

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw{(...)};
draw.on('drawend', function(event){(...)};
```

But so far I have no clue on what information I can get from the event and how to match it with the layer.

Comment: It is not clear how many layers do you have. Maybe you show your code.

Comment: I now get the right layer, so the question now sums up to knowing if a layer A (which contains curves) intersectects layer B (which contains a surface which can be a circle or a polygon). I tried turf library's turf.intersect but I get "cyclic object reference" from that library.

Comment: Can you show some code on how you are doing the intersection?

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote the question I had nearly no code apart from the mentionnes OL3 layer/features and was not yet use at all to OL3. Since then I found a solution which I should post if I find the time to write it clearly.